# Resharper setting to analyze code only when I press Enter at the end of the line?

Tags: resharper, code-analysis

While I'm editing a line of code, I'd like to have access to Code Completion, etc.

But most of the time while editing, before having pressed Enter, syntax color coding, squigglies, and variable type hints appear and move things.

I would like to finish editing the line and analyze the line only when I press Enter.

I've checked the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Index.html), and I can turn it off entirely under **Code Inspection > Settings**. But there's no setting there to wait until I'm done.

I have found that you can swap Tab and Enter, but that's for Code Completion only.

I have the latest stable Visual Studio 2022 and the latest stable Resharper version.

Any solution that doesn't change a character or spacing on the line I'm editing is eligible. So it can analyze the line as long as it doesn't do this. But I'd prefer to defer analysis until I press the Enter key at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. As you already mentioned, you can disable certain things, but you cannot defer its execution. This is a basic paradigm across Visual Studio and ReSharper (Rider as well) to give you feedback *while* editing, not *after*. Maybe using VS Code with the C# extension is an option for you.

Comment: If this suffices your needs, please consider accepting it as an answer so that the question gets closed :)